# SSL/TLS Handshake before or after

Tags: ssl, tcp, handshake

If I use TCP as the transport protocol and want to secure the line with SSL or TLS, does SSL/TLS Handshake happens after TCP Handshake?.

Comment: Of course it does. There is no connection for the TLS handshake to happen over until the TCP handshake is complete. *Everything* in TLS is layered over TCP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSL/TLS works on top an already established communication channel, i.e. the TCP connection has to be established (and thus the TCP handshake successfully finished) before the TLS handshake can start.